# Real-time error reporting from windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is there anything that can be done to get real-time error reporting from windows phone devices? I have code in my app that will catch errors to let users send them via email, but it's just not happening and yet I keep seeing errors being logged, very few but still occurs every few days, via the Dev center but without details, which is completely useless to me.

Any suggestions, tools, other would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If app crashes try get your info from UnhandledException event and write it to some kind of log file so next time app launches you can send those logs [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

I've used it in WP8 application and worked fine. To get usefull information from exception do `arg.ExceptionObject.ToString()`

Comment: Hi, I'm definitely capturing the error and I'm presenting the user with the option to email it but no one ever seems to report anything back. I also write it to a log that can be accessed (and emailed) via the About page but again, no feedback is ever sent.

Comment: What I've done was when the app launches, program checks if there are any logs to send if there are and WI-Fi connection is available then logs are sent automatically BUT not via email but error log is sent to Service. Because its business app for our customer we don't ask if they want to send log just send it they want good product we want error logs :)

Comment: Fair enough if it's for business but I'm just an individual and the app is free, so I don't want to get overheads with having to host web services on a website or similar, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use Application Insights to find out what users are doing with your app,

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/get-usage-data-vs.aspx

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at it this evening.